# jquery: how to remove the div and rebind it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have added multiple `<li>`'s to a `<ul>` dynamically through jQuery. I.e. I am dynamically generating the taskdetails.

```
if ($('#ulTask li').length == 0)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://xyz/x",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError
    });
    function OnSuccess(TaskData){        
        var TaskDataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(TaskData.d);                
        $.each(TaskDataObj, function (i, v) {
            $("#ulTask").append('<li id="liTask'+TaskDataObj[i].TaskId+'"><div id="divTask'+TaskDataObj[i].TaskId+'"><img id="imgCollapse'+TaskDataObj[i].TaskId+'" alt="' + TaskDataObj[i].TaskId + '" src="Images/story_collapsed1.png" onclick="javascript:FillTaskDetails('+TaskId+');"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;'+ TaskTypeUrl +'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">' + TaskDataObj[i].TaskName + '</a></div></li>');
        });
    }
    function OnError(request, status, error){
        alert(request.statusText);
    }
}
```

Then for the image click event I am adding a seperate `<div>` to the corresponding `<li>` tag. I.e. for each taskdetails I am adding subtask details dynamically.

```
function FillTaskDetails(TaskId)
{
    var index = $("#liTask"+taskId+"").index("#divTaskDetail");
    var CheckDivObj = $("#liTask"+taskId+"").children();
    var text = CheckDivObj.prevObject[0].innerHTML;
    var index = text.indexOf("divTaskDetail");    
    if(index == -1)
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://abc/a",
        data: '{"TaskId":' + id + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        aysnc: false,
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError
     });
    function OnSuccess(TaskData){   
        var TaskDataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(TaskData.d);
        var divStr = "";
        var taskType = trim(getTaskType(TaskDataObj[0].TaskType));
        var taskStatys = trim(getTaskStatus(TaskDataObj[0].Status));
        var objSubTaskList = jQuery.parseJSON(subTaskList);

        divStr = divStr + "<div id='divTaskDetail'>";
        var objsubTaskDetails = GetSuTaskDetails(TaskDataObj[0].TaskId);
        $.each(objsubTaskDetails, function(i,v){
            divStr = divStr + "<p>"+objsubTaskDetails[i].subtaskName+"</p>";
        });
        divStr = divStr + "<input class='txttaskValues' type='text'/>";
        divStr = divStr + "<input type='button' class='btnAddCanel' value='Add' onClick='javascript:AddSubTask("+TaskDataObj[0].TaskId+");'/>";
        divStr = divStr + "</div>";
    }
}
```

In the add button I am able to add data to database successfully but I am not able to refresh the div("divTaskDetail") tag dynamically.

```
function AddSubTask(id)
{
    alert($("#txtSubTaskName").val());
    alert(id);
    var id1 = parseInt(id), SubTaskName = $("#txtSubTaskName").val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://trs/t",
      data: "{'taskId': '" + id + "','subTaskName':'" + SubTaskName + "'}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: OnSuccess,
      error: OnError
   });
   function OnSuccess(TaskStatus){
       alert(TaskStatus.d);
       var index = $("#liTask"+id+"").index("#divTaskDetail");
       var CheckDivObj = $("#liTask"+id+"").children();
       var childNode = CheckDivObj.prevObject[0];
       if(childNode.innerHTML.indexOf("divTaskDetail") != -1)
       {
        $("#liTask"+id+"").children()[1].remove();//here i want to remove this div and rebind it
       }
}
```

I wanted to remove the div and rebind it with the new data i.e. with the newly added one.

Can anyone explain how I can do that?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it and then add it again. Why not just remove its current data and add the new ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery [.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) API, to remove elements from DOM.